# Difference between Master Page and MVC View Master page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, master-pages

Please check below screen shot. What is main difference between Master Page and MVC View Master page.

When I should use Master page and when I should use MVC View Master page.

Thanks.

[alt text http://mahingupta.com/mahingupta/public/img/MsaterPage.png](http://mahingupta.com/mahingupta/public/img/MsaterPage.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is the base class. In an ASP.NET MVC application you should use MVC View Master Page which derives from [ViewMasterPage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.viewmasterpage.aspx) and you have access to helpers and it can be strongly typed to a model.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov : What are the reasons why I should not use normal Master Page.??

Comment: Because in a normal master page you don't have access to helpers.

Comment: In the MVC Master Page you also get access to ViewData[]